# Problem defining typingStart to a specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to get my discord bot to send this message only if the user starts typing in the defined channel, and not other text channels. I don't get any errors, the bot just doesn't send a message. What am I doing wrong here? Can `typingStart` be defined to a specific channel?

```
const Join2_channel =  "972135774921247676"

bot.on("typingStart", (message , channel) => {
   if (channel.id === Join2_channel) {
      message.send('Type !join');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`typingStart`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-typingStart) event takes two parameters; `channel` (the channel the user started typing in) and `user` (that started typing), in this order.

In your current code you're checking if the `user.id` is `972135774921247676` and as that's a channel's snowflake, it won't match. You need to update your callback function:

```js
bot.on("typingStart", (channel, user) => {
  if (channel.id === Join2_channel) {
      channel.send('Type !join');
   }
});
```

Comment: Sure thing! Where would I put a timeout function to pause the bot after sending the message so he doesn't spam every 7 secs?

Comment: Do you mean something like this to delay the message? `if (channel.id === Join2_channel) { setTimeout(() => channel.send('Type !join'), 7000); }`. Or you probably want to use [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes debounce sounds what I'm looking for. How would I apply it to what I'm trying to do. Thanks again!